# How to set up links and tooltip in d3 force directed layout

Tags: json, d3.js, svg

I am trying to put together a force directed layout in d3 but am having some problems getting my links in. I am trying to create links that connect from each of my nodes in the json array to static svg nodes that I created. Do I need to have a json file that includes both links and nodes? Or can I reference them separately. What am I missing in my code to make this happen?

Here's the json file for nodes:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq

And here's the json file for links:

```js
var links = [
    { source: academiaNode, target: 0 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 1 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 2 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 3 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 4 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 5 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 6 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 7 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 8 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 9 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 10 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 11 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 12 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 13 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 14 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 15 },
    { source: ngoNode, target: 16 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 17 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 18 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 19 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 20 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 21 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 22 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 23 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 24 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 25 },
    { source: academiaNode, target: 26 },
    { source: commonwealthNode, target: 27 },
    { source: legislatureNode, target: 28 },
    { source: legislatureNode, target: 29 },
    { source: legislatureNode, target: 30 },
    { source: legislatureNode, target: 31 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 32 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 33 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 34 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 35 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 36 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 37 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 38 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 39 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 40 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 41 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 42 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 43 },
    { source: federalNode, target: 44 },
    { source: militaryNode, target: 45 },
    { source: militaryNode, target: 46 }
];
```

I'm also trying to set up a click function on my nodes so that an svg rectangle expands out from the left of the screen and displays the description of each node. You can see the description I am trying to display in the nodes json file. Here's the d3 code I'm working with to power the visualization.

```js
    <script type= "text/javascript">

        var w = 1000,
            h = 650;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .style("border", "1px solid black");

        var data; // a global

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([w, h])
            .linkDistance([150])
            .charge([-1050])
            .gravity(0.5)
            .on("tick", tick);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
        
        var academiaNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 125)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue");
        
        var ngoNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 225)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue");
        
        var federalNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 325)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue")
      
        var commonwealthNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 425)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue");
       
        var legislatureNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 525)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue");
        
        var commonwealthNode = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 625)
            .attr("cy", 300)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "lightblue");
        
        var circles = svg.selectAll(".node");

        d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rnhq", function(error, json) {
            if (error) return console.warn(error);
            data = json;
            console.log(data);

        force.nodes(data).links()
          .start();

// Update nodes.
  
    circles = circles.data(data);

    circles.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = circles.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .style("opacity", 0.75)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("click", click)    
      .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r",  function(d) { return d.sector == "Academia" ? 1:5 });
            
    nodeEnter.attr("cursor", "pointer");
            
// Update links
    var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(data.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px");
            
    links.exit().remove();        
            
    function mouseover() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr('r', 10);
    }
            
    function mouseout() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr('r', 5);
    }

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", ".75em")
      .attr("dy", "-0.85em").text(function (d) { return d.name });                   
    
     var tooltip = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 1000)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 900)
            .attr("height", 700)
            .attr("opacity", 0.85);            

            
    function click() {
        d3.select(tooltip).transition()
            .duration(450)
            .attr("x", 650)
    };             

    });

function tick() {
    links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    circles.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
};
        


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for the links is: source: `index_number`, target: `index_number`

You should have in the source and target the same: or the index number or just an id (which has to be also in the json for the nodes), or a name, ..

So if you don't connect your links with the index_number then you have to add something like this:

```
var nodeById = d3.map();

  graph.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
  nodeById.set(node.id, node);
});

graph.links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodeById.get(link.source);
  link.target = nodeById.get(link.target);
});
```

Here in that example i connected the likes with the node.id.
My json file looked like this:

```
{"nodes": [
{
"id":9053,
"name":"0009053",
"category":"AP"
}
,{
"id":9136,
"name":"Curon Venosta",
"category":"TCS"
}
,{
"id":9116,
"name":"Dummy",
"category":"EQP"
}
,{
"id":9286,
"name":"T",
"category":"EQ"
}
],
"links": [
{
"source":9136,
"target":9053
}
,{
"source":9116,
"target":9136
}
,{
"source":9286,
"target":9116
}
]}
```

See also this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/533daf20348023dfdd76

Hope this helps you a bit..